Script to limit vendor bill access to only view records user approved or is pending approval
We need to restrict the visibility on vendor bills based on approver or role conditions. We are using SuiteApprovals and a workflow for 3-way match. The goal is to only have users view the bills they have approved or are a pending approver on unless admin or controller role. We also want to make sure they can't circumvent by running a saved search.
Has anyone created a script to do this?
Tried a workflow setting a checkbox to determine if access should be given based on next approver field - intermittently working.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

you can not remove/stop running a saved search for users. Until you remove the complete remove access Find Transaction at Role -> permission level, Which will remove all search actions for transaction records.
Other options to limit access

Create a saved search with your desired conditions
In the same saved search Subtab -> role section -> PREFERRED LIST VIEW (tick it) -> you can also set for the role you want to restrict -> list, results (tick it).
Maybe you can use workflow or before load in the user event script throw a custom error based on the condition. Restrict view access for not approved vendor bills

